# How can I open a new window in Google Chrome Metro Mode?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

Whenever I click on Open a New Window in Google Chrome (Metro Mode) it opens a new tab. However when I click on open a Incognito mode I see a rectangular box which allows me to switch between two windows.

Why can't it open a new window instead of opening a new tab?

Comment: Metro apps can't have multiple windows, so of course opening a new window in Chrome Metro doesn't work

Comment: But that's not the case in Incognito mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot open multiple windows in modern UI chrome, and that's the case *even for incognito*.

You can see that it's obviously still the same application, because there is a switch between the 2 modes:

[image]