# How can I open a new window in Google Chrome Metro Mode? is there any plugin?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, modern-ui, browser-tabs

I see the question [How can I open a new window in Google Chrome Metro Mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/498882/how-can-i-open-a-new-window-in-google-chrome-metro-mode)

But i need a plugin or a tool for making a new window!!

New window is not a special feature just it have fresh tab list!!! so i think a simple and easy to use tab manager may exist to help doing this.

i tried extention "too many tabs for chrome" and similar! but it is hard to use and it doesn't what i need.

I usually have about more than 100 tabs. and using chrome in windows mode get always about 5~10% of my cpu and about 4Gb of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Unfortunately there is no plugin in Google chrome.